# Selenium Webdriver: The method alert() is undefined for the type WebDriver.TargetLocator

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, alerts

I am trying to handle alerts using Selenium Webdriver, according the selenium documentation the correct implementation is:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
```

However I am getting error message The method alert() is undefined for the type WebDriver.TargetLocator

what version of Selenium 2 has this web driver api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using selenium 2.3 and it works for me. From what I've seen, alerts only work with windows that ONLY have the ok button. Thats where you put the alert.accept(); statement in. Another problem that I've seen with alerts is that it may jump over the alert so you may have to have a wait statement for that specific alert. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Alerts are not be supported by HmltUnit driver. In HtmlUnitDriver.java (Selenium 2.0.6) :

```
public Alert alert() {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("alert()");
}
```

Which driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a separate import statement for Alert:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
```

I had the same issue.